# How to determine weekly pay in C debug error with ;

Tags: c, debugging, emacs, printf

I'm creating a program that calculates weekly pay and in which overtime is 1.5 of the weekly salary.
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  double payrate;
  double hours;
  double weeklypay = hours * payrate;
  double overtimehours = hours - 40;
  double overtimepay = weeklypay * 1.5;
  double overtimesalary =  weeklypay + (overtimehours * overtimepay);

  printf("What is your standard hourly pay rate?\n");
  scanf("%d",&payrate);
  printf("How many hours do you work in a week?\n");
  scanf("%d",&hours);

  if (hours <= 40)
    printf("This means your weekly pay is %d . \n", weeklypay);

  else (hours > 40)
     printf("This means your weekly pay is %d . \n", overtimesalary);


  return 0;
}
```

I keep getting this error when running my program and I'm totally confused as to why?

```
 expected ‘;’ before ‘printf’
```

I realize I'm doing something stupid; if someone could please help me realize my mistake I'd be truly grateful.

Comment: Why did you tag this with `emacs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  if (hours <= 40)
    printf("This means your weekly pay is %d . \n", weeklypay);

  else (hours > 40)
     printf("This means your weekly pay is %d . \n", overtimesalary);
```

You miss the *if* in the else:

```
  if (hours <= 40)
    printf("This means your weekly pay is %d . \n", weeklypay);

  else if (hours > 40)
     printf("This means your weekly pay is %d . \n", overtimesalary);
```

Or in this case, you could just remove it:

```
  if (hours <= 40)
    printf("This means your weekly pay is %d . \n", weeklypay);

  else
     printf("This means your weekly pay is %d . \n", overtimesalary);
```